# Erwirb Vaseline und Quark(,) bitte

Tags: comma, imperative

Ich weiß, dass es nicht obligatorisch ist, ein Komma vor *bitte* zu setzen, wenn es am Anfang des Satzes steht. Wenn es inmitten des Satzes steht, ist das Komma völlig inkorrekt, soweit ich das weiß. Aber wenn es am Ende ist, ist das Komma optional oder obligatorisch?

`Erwirb Vaseline und Quark(,) bitte.`

Comment: Ein Hinweis für den Alltag. Niemand sagt "erwirb x und y". Man sagt "Kaufe x und y", oder "(wenn du einkaufen gehst) bringe x und y mit". Der Inhalt der Frage bleibt aber auch mit "kaufen" der selbe.

Comment: Ist "niemand" nicht ein wenig spekulativ und womöglich zu verallgemeinernd gesprochen?

Comment: Vielleicht. Aber "so gut wie niemand" trifft es bestimmt gut ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meiner Auffassung nach handelt es sich bei diesem *bitte* um einen Nachtrag. Dem Auffordernden ist aufgefallen, dass der blanke Imperativ unhöflich wirkt, und mildert den Satz durch ein nachgeschobenes *bitte* ab. Dann greift § 77 der Rechtschreibregeln, wonach ein Nachtrag per Komma abgetrennt wird. Das Komma entspricht also einer Denkpause und ist obligatorisch.

Comment: Also, meinen Sie, dass nur diese Variante korrekt ist? *Erwirb Vaseline und Quark, bitte.*

Comment: @TeerseifemögenderMr.Kater: Die angegebene Regel fordert das Komma. Meiner Meinung nach kann man das nur umgehen, indem man *bitte* an den Anfang setzt.